# Помогите пожалуйста с решением задачи

Tags: python, python-3.x

На склад, который имеет форму прямоугольного параллелепипеда, привезли ноутбуки, упакованные в коробки. Каждая коробка также имеет форму прямоугольного параллелепипеда. По правилам хранения коробки с ноутбуками должны быть размещены на складе с выполнением следующих двух условий:

Стороны коробок должны быть параллельны сторонам склада.
Коробку при помещении на склад разрешается расположить где угодно (с выполнением предыдущего условия), в том числе на другой коробке, но все коробки должны быть ориентированы одинаково (т.е. нельзя одну коробку расположить “стоя”, а другую —“лежа”)
Напишите программу, которая по размерам склада и размерам коробки с ноутбуком определит максимальное количество ноутбуков, которое может быть размещено на складе.

Формат ввода

Программа получает на вход шесть натуральных чисел. Первые три задают длину, высоту и ширину склада. Следующие три задают соответственно длину, высоту и ширину коробки с ноутбуком.

Формат вывода

Программа должна вывести одно число — максимальное количество ноутбуков, которое может быть размещено на складе.

```
a, b, c = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
a1, a2, a3 = int(input()), int(input()), int(input())
ma = max(a, b, c)
s = sum([a, b, c]) - max(a, b, c) - min(a, b, c)
mi = min(a, b, c)
ma1 = max(a1, a2, a3)
s1 = sum([a1, a2, a3]) - max(a1, a2, a3) - min(a1, a2, a3)
mi1 = min(a1, a2, a3)
t = mi // mi1
t1 = s // s1
t2 = ma // ma1
print(t * t1 * t2)
```

Подскажите что не так и правилен ли ход мыслей. Программа проваливается на одном из тестов

Comment: Вы должны посчитать количество ноутов в столбике максимально возможной высоты при разных ориентациях (3 варианта). Затем перебрать все возможные замощения пола тремя прямоугольниками, для каждого посчитать общее количество ноутов. И вывести максимум. Для такого алгоритма Ваша программа слишком коротка...

Comment: Благодарствую!!!